# Vaildate text boxes and combo boexs in vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio, combobox, textbox

Am trying to validate the data in the text-boxes and combo-boxes in my vb.net program that  is connected to an access database.

I have used the following code below but get an error message;

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdadd.Click

  ShowAllStock.StockDataTableAdapter.Insert(Me.cboitemtype.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.cbocompany.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, Me.TextBox4.Text)
  ShowAllStock.StockDataTableAdapter.Fill(ShowAllStock.Logins1DataSet.StockData)

  If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In Your Name", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Fill In Your Name")
  ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In the Total Cost Box", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Enter Cost")
  ElseIf cboitemtype.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Item Type", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Select Item Type")
  ElseIf cbocompany.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Company Delivered By", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Select Company Delivered By")
  ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In Quantity", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Fill In Quantity")
  Else
    MsgBox("Records Added Successfully")
    cboitemtype.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    cbocompany.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Please explain what problem you are having, and what error message you are receiving.

Comment: I want to vaild the text boxes and combo boxes in the vb.net form before I when clicked on the add button.

Comment: But everytime I get a error message 'InvaildCast Exception was unhandled'

Answer (score 0):

If your code is correct, which it maybe? though i haven't checked it over.

Yet, as your attempting to SAVE the data before validating it, maybe that it whats causing your error?

To start with swap some of the lines of your code over so it looks like below, then when you run it again if you get any errors update your question with the errors you get.

```
Private Sub cmdadd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdadd.Click
  '-> Try to validate the data
  If TextBox2.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In Your Name", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Fill In Your Name")
  ElseIf TextBox4.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In the Total Cost Box", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Enter Cost")
  ElseIf cboitemtype.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Item Type", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Select Item Type")
  ElseIf cbocompany.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Select Company Delivered By", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Select Company Delivered By")
  ElseIf TextBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Please Fill In Quantity", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Please Fill In Quantity")
  Else
    '-> Data was found to be valid
    Try
      ShowAllStock.StockDataTableAdapter.Insert(Me.cboitemtype.Text, Me.TextBox2.Text, Me.cbocompany.Text, Me.TextBox3.Text, Me.TextBox4.Text)
      Try
        ShowAllStock.StockDataTableAdapter.Fill(ShowAllStock.Logins1DataSet.StockData)
        MsgBox("Records Added Successfully")
      Catch
        '-> Error occurred FILLING record!
      End Try
    Catch
      '-> Error occurred INSERTING record!
    End Try
    cboitemtype.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    cbocompany.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox4.Text = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

Basically changing the lines over will do the VALIDATION first, THEN only, will it try to save the data.